# Spring Data JPA: No property found for type (Field name contains query method predicate keywords)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

So I've been trying to wrap my brain around this error. So I'm getting a pretty standard error which I understand what it is telling me I just don't see how it's getting this error. So here is the error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property stored found for type StorageItemEntity! Did you mean 'storedIn'?
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:90) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:437) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:413) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:366) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:348) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:331) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:249) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:250) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:383) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:384) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:89) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
```

So pretty standard error right? Ok so it's telling me that no property 'stored' is found for my entity. Makes sense but I can't seem to understand why because I didn't define stored. Alright so here is the query that is messing it all up

```
@Repository
public interface StorageItemDao extends JpaRepository<StorageItemEntity, Long> {
    
    // All other methods omitted for sake of keeping it short
    public List<StorageItemEntity> findAllByStoredIn(StorageType storedIn);

}
```

And here is the StorageItemEntity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "storage_item")
public class StorageItemEntity implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5373908574936516693L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    
    @NotEmpty(message = "Storage item name can not be empty")
    @Size(max = 100, message = "Storage item name can not exceed 100 characters")
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @Range(min = 0, message = "Amount in storage can not be less than 0")
    @Column(name = "amount")
    private int amount;
    
    @Range(min = 0, message = "Amount expected in storage per week can not be less than 0")
    @Column(name = "amount_expected")
    private int amountExpected;
    
    @NotNull(message = "Storage in type can not be empty")
    @Column(name = "stored_in")
    private StorageType storedIn;
    
    @Size(max = 500, message = Constants.ADDITIONAL_INFO_EXCEED)
    @Column(name = "additional_info")
    private String additionalInfo;
    
    @NotNull(message = "You need to have a vendor associated to this item")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "vendor_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private VendorEntity vendor;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "type_of_storage_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private TypeOfStorageEntity typeOfStorage;

    // All getters, setters, and constructors are omitted
}
```

I would also like to note that StorageType is a pretty standard Enumeration. This is not the error but it is a good note just in case. So why would I be getting a "No property 'stored' found for type StorageItemEntity" if I never defined said stored in my JPA method?

Thank you

Comment: looks like your column name for `stored_in` is `storedIn`

Comment: I agree which is why I did name my function in the JPA Repository ```findAllByStoredIn```

Comment: I guess the problem is "In" in "findByStoredIn" is a [query keyword](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/repository-query-keywords.html)

Comment: @samabcde That's actually a really good point. I didn't think about that. Yep that was absolutely the reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like `In` is a keyword used by Spring query derivation. So it expects a `stored` property which is `In` value provided in arguments.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#appendix.query.method.predicate

You need to use `@Query` annotation to get what you want.

Comment: Yep In was the problem and that was my bad. I changed my variable name as it's better to just avoid that keyword altogether and so that I can make my variable make more sense

Answer (score 2):

I think It is the problem of column name and variable name in the JPA model,
If you want to use findAllByStoredIn you can use @Query annotation like this.

The Repository class like

```
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {
      
    @Query("SELECT a FROM Account a WHERE a.userName = :username")
    Account findByUsername(@Param("username") String username);
}
```

And the Model class like

```
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @NotNull
    @UniqueUsername(message="Username already exists")
    @Size(min = 6, max = 255, message = "Username have to be grater than 6 characters")
    @Column(name="user_name",unique = true)
    private String userName;

    }
```

Comment: This is also a good answer for anyone looking

Answer (score 0):

just this is enough for the issue.
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM Account a WHERE a.username = :username")
Account findByUsername(@Param("username") String username);
```

}